# Building haskell-ide-engine error - "unknown symbol `ucnv_getMaxCharSize_58'"

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Environment:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- MINGW 64 bit
- stack Version 1.5.1, Git revision 600c1f01435a10d127938709556c1682ecfd694e x86_64 hpack-0.17.1

When running `stack install` I first got the following error:

```
Missing C libraries: icuuc, icuin, icudt
```

[image]

To fix it I run: `stack exec -- pacman -Sy mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-icu`

After that the build stopped on another error which seemed to have to do with stack building multiple things at same time.

On running again it passed by that error and it printed the following error:

```
haskell-lsp-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
Progress: 1/13
--  While building package haskell-lsp-0.1.0.0 using:
  C:\sr\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab build lib:haskell-lsp exe:lsp-hello --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: D:\Sources\haskell-ide-engine\.stack-work\logs\haskell-lsp-0.1.0.0.log

Preprocessing library haskell-lsp-0.1.0.0...
[ 2 of 10] Compiling Language.Haskell.LSP.TH.ClientCapabilities ( src\Language\Haskell\LSP\TH\ClientCapabilities.hs, .stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\Language\Haskell\LSP\TH\ClientCapabilities.o )
ghc.EXE: unable to load package `text-icu-0.7.0.1'
ghc.EXE: addLibrarySearchPath: D:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib\ (Win32 error 3): The system cannot find the path specified.
ghc.EXE: C:\sr\snapshots\c7200f2c\lib\x86_64-windows-ghc-8.0.2\text-icu-0.7.0.1-EllpGYmNw3bJ3FIJMPisuJ\HStext-icu-0.7.0.1-EllpGYmNw3bJ3FIJMPisuJ.o: unknown symbol `ucnv_getMaxCharSize_58'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Github Issue: https://github.com/alanz/haskell-lsp/issues/56

Comment: I think the bug is because it is looking for the path in the wrong drive: D instead of C: `ghc.EXE: addLibrarySearchPath: D:\Users\Razvan\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20150512\mingw64\lib\ (Win32 error 3): The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210863/unable-to-load-hmatrix-with-stack-ghci) is another question with basically the exact same issue (foreign lib, ghc looking in D:\.. instead of C:\.., and (perhaps coincidentally) also using pacman for the foreign lib). This isn't to do with `c++`, `icu`, or `haskell-lsp`. I suggest you try to reproduce a build w/o `stack` - if it no longer fails, post this on the `stack` issue tracker. Otherwise, I'd guess it is either an issue with GHC (less likely) or pacman (more likely).

Comment: @user2407038 It is weird since I can't even reproduce the error anymore. Thank you for the obervations, was suspecting it might be ghc issue also, but not sure.